# How can I get text from an embed with discord.py?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I have a bot in discord.py that I would like to add a role to users mentioned in an embed. It can add the role if you mention the user regularly, but how can I get the text from the description of the embed? Does it return some kind of dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Embeds` have a [`description`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.description) field. You would have to somehow convert that text to `Member`s if you wanted to do much of anything with it, which would be helped by the use of [`MemberConverter`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/converter.py#L79-L102).